# Microsoft .Net library for implementing EAP-TLS in Windows and Linux

Tags: c#, linux, windows, wifi, .net-6.0

I'm working on a Microsoft .Net 6 project that requires me to implement EAP-TLS programmatically. I researched for a couple of days and found the following libraries that could help me.

1. SimpleWifi - https://github.com/mahdi-ataollahi/simplewifi
2. ManagedNativeWifi - https://github.com/emoacht/ManagedNativeWifi

However, the SimpleWifi library internally creates WLAN profiles in the Windows environment. I'm unsure whether the same WLAN profiles can be used in Linux OS. And the ManagedNativeWifi internally uses Win32 APIs to achieve the functionality.

The worst-case scenario would be to investigate how WLAN profiles are created in Windows and Linux and generate them programmatically and execute commands in the software depending on the OS/environment.

Is there any Wi-Fi library I can use to implement the EAP-TLS authentication mechanism with C# .Net 6 ecosystem for both Windows and Linux?